# SAVEPOINT errors in oracle database 10g express edition

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Whenever I use SAVEPOINT in Oracle Database 10g Express Edition it gives me errors continuously either I use "SAVEPOINT A", "SAVEPOINT A;" AND "SAVEPOINT <A.>;"

Help me in this

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of difficult to debug code you can't see. I don't have 10g**XE**, but - this is 10gEE; I don't expect it to behave differently in that matter:

```
SQL> select * From v$version;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.5.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production

SQL> begin
  2    savepoint a;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Therefore, perhaps you'd want to share your code so that we'd see what you did and how Oracle responded.

Comment: its still not working dude

Comment: It is working for me, dude. Do you not see? "Procedure successfully completed". Re-read my last sentence and do as I asked; otherwise, you're pretty much on your own.